# Memory management problem (release UIVIewCotroller)

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiview, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I develop the game for iPad (composing image from puzzles). In my menu i choose level difficult (simple, medium or hard). After selecting the main playing field will be shown. 
Here's place, where i create the main playing field:

```
- (void)simpleDiffButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    if (simpleDiffButton == button) {
        UIView *mySuperView = self.view.superview;

        mainGame = [[MainGame alloc] initWithMode:1 andImage:nil]; //mainGame variable is declared in header file like: MainGame *mainGame;
        mainGame.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        [mySuperView addSubview: mainGame.view];
}
```

}

After this playing field is appears (there are a lot of sublayers adding to self.view.layer) and i can interact with it. When i want to quit from it, i click button "back". (here i want to release my viewcontroller)

```
- (void)backToMenuButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    if (nextImageClick == YES) {
        return;
    }   
    if (backToMenuButton == button) {
     self.view.layer.sublayers = nil;  //here's an exception
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    }
}
```

After clicking "back" button everything is ok. And i can choose difficultly level again. A choose a level, and after it clicking "back" button again and at this place application crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).
As i understand "**self.view.layer.sublayers = nil**" causes the exception.
Without it everything is ok. But memory is leaking. And after several minutes of playing app was crashes (memory warning 2).
I cannot solve the problem for about a week. I don't understand what to do to release my viewcontroller (or i need to release all sublayers in controller?).

Please, someone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn on NSZombieEnabled and check out Debugger and Console when it crush, it can give some more info about the problem.

P.S. NSZombieEnabled : http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled (you may want to try useing .gdbinit).

P.P.S:
Btw, there might be some other problem in the line where "mainGame = [[MainGame alloc] initW...". -- where [mainGame release] is called? (it should be called as many as simpleDiffButtonClicked which allocs new instance of MainGame to mainGame variable (every time))

Comment: Thanks for reply, navX! I'll read about NSZombieEnabled (thanks). What about releasing the mainGame variable - if i do this `[mainGame.view release];`, the application will crashes (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). Maybe there's another way to present a view (not `addSubview:`)? I've read about presentmodalview method, but it's not working for me and it's not that i need.